# Prevent Azure api app authentication for specific url paths

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, authorization

We've enabled authentication on our Azure api app and it's working well.  Clients are required to retrieve a oauth2 token for authentication and authorization to the service.  Our service is a Express Node.js application and we are leveraging apidoc for the service documentation.

I can't figure out from the authentication configuration how to allow access to a url path without requiring authentication. For example:

https://app-myservice-staging-001.azurewebsites.net/constituents should require authentication

but the documentation url

https://app-myservice-staging-001.azurewebsites.net/apidoc should not

Current with authentication enabled everything under https://app-myservice-staging-001.azurewebsites.net is protected.

Is this possible and if so where do I need to look?

Comment: Use [File-based configuration in Azure App Service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-file-based#configuration-file-reference) and set globalValidation.excludedPaths

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on link provided by [amit_g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495041/amit-g). We opted to add our excludepath directly to our authsettingsV2 config using the Azure Resource Explorer since the /apidoc/* path applies to all our services.